# SwiftUI: EmptyView().onAppear {} formally exists, but not called when view is presented?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI:

```
EmptyView().onAppear {
//Not called
}
```

`onAppear` formally exists, but not called when view is presented?

Answer (score 3):

Consider `EmptyView` is just as interface stub (to put something where view is required but at some moment there is nothing to provide). It is in a fact not inserted into view hierarchy, so `.onAppear` is not called, because nothing appears.

Comment: if you put a single `Rectangle` and add a `.hidden()` modifier that could also works.

Answer (score 3):

The way it functions is annoyingly undocumented.

If you *only* have an `EmptyView` for `Body`, `onAppear` is called on it.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EmptyView().onAppear { fatalError() } // crash 
  }
}
```

Otherwise, it's not. E.g. This doesn't crash.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EmptyView().onAppear { fatalError() }
    EmptyView().onAppear { fatalError() }
  }
}
```

Comment: If ContentView is not a root view, then onAppear callback is not called as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add:

```
Rectangle()
   .hidden()
   .onAppear {
     // TODO: Do something
   }
```