# SwiftUI .task not invoking

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason, the `.task` is not invoking my function automatically when the view gets open. If I call the function using `Button("click") { Task { ... } }`, then it works.
Why does the `.task` not work here?

```
import SwiftUI

struct BookTextView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: BookTextViewModel = BookTextViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("HELLO!")
        Group {
            switch viewModel.result {
            case .empty:
                EmptyView()
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
            case .failure(let error):
                Text(error.localizedDescription)
                //            ErrorView(error: error, retryHandler: viewModel.load)
            case .success(let bookText):
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text(bookText.text)
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }.task {
            do {
                try await viewModel.load()
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My model

```
import SwiftUI

@MainActor class BookTextViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum AsyncResult<Success> {
        case empty
        case loading
        case success(Success)
        case failure(Error)
    }
    
    @Published var bookText: BookText?
    @Published var result: AsyncResult<BookText> = .empty
    

    func load() async {
        print("loading?")
        ...
```

This is how i call the view from another component

```
 detail: {
            BookTextView()
```

Comment: This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72601988/5133585). `task` is similar to `onAppear`, in that they both run something when the view first appears. `EmptyView` never actually "appears", so `task` never gets run.

Comment: try using a `VStack{ Text....}.task {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.task` runs when something appears, since you have `EmptyView()` that doesn't appear, remove that and move your `Text("HELLO!")` into the `.empty` case and it should fix it.

`.task` will also run when it re-appears (e.g. going back) so you might want to check the model is not already loaded so save needlessly loading it again.

Some tips to improve your code: put the text into a result enum instead of a separate var. Remove the object and just use `@State var result` because `.task` sort of already makes an object behind the scenes to manage the lifecycle. Declare your async fun somewhere else that is more easily testable by making it return something or throw.